# Retrieve data from non-existent rows in database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

First of all, this is a big system but Im using a simple example.

The code snippet:

```php
$query = "select * from table where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-13'";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num = count($rows);
if($num>0){
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Date']));
    echo $row['code'];
    echo number_format($row['price'], 0, ",", ".");
    }
```

The result of my query to fetch data from Nov 1 to Nov 13

```sql
   date    |  code  | price 
2014-11-03 | 'abc'  | 140
2014-11-04 | 'abc'  | 110
2014-11-05 | 'abc'  | 85
2014-11-06 | 'abc'  | 100
2014-11-07 | 'abc'  | 120
2014-11-10 | 'abc'  | 85
2014-11-11 | 'abc'  | 97
2014-11-13 | 'abc'  | 100
```

The system generates data only when there is input price on the day. If its weekend or holiday there's no data in the database, in this case, Nov 1-2 and 8-9 are weekend and Nov 12 is holiday.

What I want to achieve is when it's holiday or weekend, it will fetch the price as the day before weekend/holiday. For the weekend algorithm I fetch it by checking if the day of the current row is saturday then it displays 2 more row with friday's data. The problem came up when it's holiday and if saturday or sunday is the first day of the month then it won't display the data.

The desired result is:

```sql
--if the price on 2014-10-31 is 90
   date    |  code  | price 
2014-11-01 | 'abc'  | 90
2014-11-02 | 'abc'  | 90
2014-11-03 | 'abc'  | 140
2014-11-04 | 'abc'  | 110
2014-11-05 | 'abc'  | 85
2014-11-06 | 'abc'  | 100
2014-11-07 | 'abc'  | 120
2014-11-08 | 'abc'  | 120
2014-11-09 | 'abc'  | 120
2014-11-10 | 'abc'  | 85
2014-11-11 | 'abc'  | 97
2014-11-12 | 'abc'  | 97
2014-11-13 | 'abc'  | 100
```

It must be easy if the date exists on database or to create a new table but it's best not to cause it's a really large database. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you implement the logic in PHP rather than trying to do it in SQL? i.e. date range requested is `xyz` - so you first check if that date range is weekend or holiday then alter the date range accordingly to the previous date and then run your query?

Comment: @Latheesan can you provide an example please? For the weekend I think I can check if sunday is on 1st or 2nd of the month then I'll re-query the price to strtotime -2 day & -3 day but I don't know how to check the holiday

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
SELECT cur_date, IFNULL(code, 'abc'), IFNULL(price,'any_price') FROM 
(
    SELECT @rowid:=date_add(@rowid, interval 1 day) as cur_date 
    FROM `table`, ( SELECT @rowid:='2014-10-31' ) as init
    WHERE @rowid < '2014-11-13' 
) TBL_DATE LEFT JOIN 
(
    select `Date`, `code`, `price` 
    from `table` 
    where `date` between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-13'
) TBL_MAIN ON TBL_DATE.cur_date = TBL_MAIN.`Date`
```

For SQL-Server:

```
DECLARE @start DATE, @end DATE;
SELECT @start = '20141101', @end = '20141113';

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
)

 SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start) as cur_date 
 FROM n;
```

Now you get the dates and the rest is same ...

Comment: `'IFNULL' is not a recognized built-in function name.` I'm sorry I forgot to tell it's SQL Server.

Comment: Try `ISNULL` instead of `IFNULL` for `SQL Server`. Also tag the question as `sql-server` not mysql!

Comment: tag edited. `Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3 Must declare the scalar variable "@rowid".` `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near ':'.`

Comment: Oh...first dynamic date generation part needed to be edited for `sql-server` ...! :(